# How to run specific commands/functions of Powershell from Command line?

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line

I have a PowerShell script with a list of commands defined in it. 
And I am trying to Create a build step in Gitlab CI when run, executes the particular script.
For this I want to first Understand:
How to run specific commands/functions of Powershell from Command line?

I have read 
[Invoking a specific function from PowerShell script from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529202/invoking-a-specific-function-from-powershell-script-from-c-sharp)
and
[Calling Powershell functions from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4179351/calling-powershell-functions-from-c-sharp/4182444#4182444)

The answers are specific to C#. 
Is there any way I can do it from the command line?

Code looks somewhat like this (myPowerScript.ps1)
I have more than One function in my powershell script. It is something like:

```
         function foo1{
         Param($Parameter1,
         $Parameter2)#
         # Foo1 implementation
         }


         function foo2{
         Param($Parameter1,
         $Parameter2)#
         # Foo2 implementation
         }

         function foo3{
         Param($Parameter1,
         $Parameter2)#
         # Foo3 implementation
         }
```

I want to invoke foo2: How do I do it? and
in this case, how does PowerShell understand which function is invoked?

Comment: Just invoke [powershell.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/core-powershell/console/powershell.exe-command-line-help).

Comment: The PowerShell console _is_ a command line.

Answer (score 0):

Your script "stuff.ps1":

```
Param($Parameter1,
      $Parameter2)

function Do-Stuff
param($Parameter1,
      $Parameter2)

#do stuff
}

Do-Stuff "Value1" "$Value2"
```

Run your ps script from commandline:

```
powershell.exe -file "stuff.ps1" "ValueforParam1" "ValueForParam2"
```

Comment: I have more than One function in my powershell script. It is something like:
function foo1{
Param($Parameter1,
      $Parameter2)#
# Foo1 implementation
}


function foo2{
Param($Parameter1,
      $Parameter2)#
# Foo2 implementation
}

function foo3{
Param($Parameter1,
      $Parameter2)#
# Fo31 implementation
}  So in this case how does powershell understand which function is invoked?

Comment: Set some parameters which define which function should run If($this -eq that){#Call function}

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
powershell -command "& { script1.ps; My-Func }"
```

Example:

```
powershell -command "& { mypowerScript.ps; foo2 }"
```