# powershell joining params while combining two scripts

Tags: c#, powershell

I have a question, I have a 2 scripts lets name then first.ps1 and second.ps1 and they look something like

first.ps1:

```
param(
    [parameter(Mandatory=$True,ValueFromPipeline=$True)][string]$filename="",
    [parameter(Mandatory=$True,ValueFromPipeline=$True)][string]$arguments=""
)

Function WriteFirst
{
    Write-Host $filename
    Write-Host $arguments
}
```

and second.ps1

```
param(
    [parameter(Mandatory=$True,ValueFromPipeline=$True)][string]$log=""
)

Function WriteSecond
{
    Write-Host $log
}
```

Now using c# (using embedded resource, nothing special) I want to join those two scripts into one, as lets say they can be separate modules from witch I can construct one final script for example first script will execute command and second will read console buffer for output.

Now question is about the pram, do I need to join then somehow or will they add up to itself or maybe override ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way that you're currently setting up the PowerShell scripts is to set the parameters at the **script** level, and then use them in the function.

A better approach would be to have the parameters at the **function** level.

```
param(
    [parameter(Mandatory=$True,ValueFromPipeline=$True)][string]$filename="",
    [parameter(Mandatory=$True,ValueFromPipeline=$True)][string]$arguments=""
)

Function WriteFirst
{
    param(
        [parameter(Mandatory=$True,ValueFromPipeline=$True)][string]$filename="",
        [parameter(Mandatory=$True,ValueFromPipeline=$True)][string]$arguments=""
    )

    Write-Host $filename
    Write-Host $arguments
}

WriteFirst -filename $filename -arguments $arguments
```

In terms of calling those functions from `c#`, [check out this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23217828/5039142). From it, you can infer that `powershell.AddScript(...).AddParameter(...)` will get you what you're asking for but I believe the `powershell.AddCommand(...).AddParameter(...)` is a better approach.