# Get-WinEvent equivalent in .NET?

Tags: .net, event-log

I'm trying to filter event logs with csharp, I need a method similar to `Get-WinEvent` command, that can filter the logs with XPATH or any other syntax.

The only method I found is [GetEventLogs()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventlog.geteventlogs?view=netframework-2.0), and it does not support filtering.

Any ideas?

Comment: You may try using [Linq To Objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/query-a-collection-of-objects) to do the querying part? Do you see any problem in that?

Comment: @SivaGopal You mean that I should use GetEventLogs to load all events in memory, then filter the collection, right?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Not quite an answer, but the source code to `Get-WinEvent` can be found here: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/233b54ed65d398604c0bfadccdc59cb81eb7e5de/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Diagnostics/GetEventCommand.cs

Comment: Powershell tries to be as convenient as possible to non-programming users.  If you like what it does then [just use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4179351/calling-powershell-functions-from-c-sharp).